# sed: replace only in part of string

Tags: sed

I have a simple playlist of song files:

```
1003 James Brown - The Boss Unknown Artist.mp3
1004 James Brown - Slaughters Theme Unknown Artist.mp3
1005 James Brown - Payback(1) Unknown Artist.mp3
...
```

I would like them in the following format:

```
1003 James_Brown_-_The_Boss_Unknown_Artist.mp3
1004 James_Brown_-_Slaughters_Theme_Unknown_Artist.mp3
...
```

Notice that the whitespace behind the number in front is NOT replaced. I have the following simple sed script:

```
sed "s/ /_/g"
```

but that replaces also the space after the number. I know how to form capture groups, but that will not help either. How can I convince sed to only apply the replacement to a portion of the input string, rather than the whole string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do

```
sed 's/ /_/g; s/_/ /'
```

I.e. first turn all spaces into underscores, then turn the first underscore back into a space.